# Chrome Crashing Report Trace

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, chromium

Whenever I opens some web link which is hosted on some other system, My chrome crashes (Using 32bit 3GB RAM OS: Windows 8). But it was working fine on other browsers

Following is the trace:

```
24bdf6a4 55b07bbd e0000008 00000001 00000001 KERNELBASE!RaiseException+0x58
    24bdf6c0 55b07b9a 216eb000 24bdf764 5506ffa0 chrome_child!base::`anonymous namespace'::OnNoMemory+0x1d [C:\b\c\b\win_clang\src\base\process\memory_win.cc @ 44]
    24bdf6cc 5506ffa0 216eb000 54a2d3dc 24bdf6d8 chrome_child!base::TerminateBecauseOutOfMemory+0xa [C:\b\c\b\win_clang\src\base\process\memory_win.cc @ 53]
    24bdf764 5506facd 24bdf79c 216eb000 0000003e chrome_child!discardable_memory::ClientDiscardableSharedMemoryManager::AllocateLockedDiscardableSharedMemory+0x19e [C:\b\c\b\win_clang\src\components\discardable_memory\client\client_discardable_shared_memory_manager.cc @ 373]
    24bdf7b0 56403990 24bdf808 216eac00 c40b8000 chrome_child!discardable_memory::ClientDiscardableSharedMemoryManager::AllocateLockedDiscardableMemory+0x207 [C:\b\c\b\win_clang\src\components\discardable_memory\client\client_discardable_shared_memory_manager.cc @ 212]
    24bdf824 564032f2 24bdf910 24bdfa18 24bdfab0 chrome_child!cc::SoftwareImageDecodeCache::GetExactSizeImageDecode+0x90 [C:\b\c\b\win_clang\src\cc\tiles\software_image_decode_cache.cc @ 605]
    24bdf8b4 56404777 24bdf910 24bdfa18 24bdfab0 chrome_child!cc::SoftwareImageDecodeCache::DecodeImageInternal+0x1b2 [C:\b\c\b\win_clang\src\cc\tiles\software_image_decode_cache.cc @ 477]
    24bdf94c 56403e13 24bdf9cc 24bdfa18 24bdfab0 chrome_child!cc::SoftwareImageDecodeCache::GetDecodedImageForDrawInternal+0x327 [C:\b\c\b\win_clang\src\cc\tiles\software_image_decode_cache.cc @ 548]
    24bdfb9c 564032de 24bdfca0 050ca638 050ca6d0 chrome_child!cc::SoftwareImageDecodeCache::GetScaledImageDecode+0x1c3 [C:\b\c\b\win_clang\src\cc\tiles\software_image_decode_cache.cc @ 728]
    24bdfc2c 56402dfe 24bdfca0 050ca638 050ca6d0 chrome_child!cc::SoftwareImageDecodeCache::DecodeImageInternal+0x19e [C:\b\c\b\win_clang\src\cc\tiles\software_image_decode_cache.cc @ 479]
    24bdfcd4 564068c0 050ca638 050ca6d0 00000000 chrome_child!cc::SoftwareImageDecodeCache::DecodeImage+0x10e [C:\b\c\b\win_clang\src\cc\tiles\software_image_decode_cache.cc @ 408]
    24bdfd48 54d711bc 030a8a64 030a8a48 050ca610 chrome_child!cc::`anonymous namespace'::SoftwareImageDecodeTaskImpl::RunOnWorkerThread+0x70 [C:\b\c\b\win_clang\src\cc\tiles\software_image_decode_cache.cc @ 119]
    24bdfd98 54add477 00000001 030a8a48 0311111c chrome_child!content::CategorizedWorkerPool::RunTaskInCategoryWithLockAcquired+0x6a [C:\b\c\b\win_clang\src\content\renderer\categorized_worker_pool.cc @ 361]
    24bdfdb0 54add417 0311111c 030a8a60 031110c8 chrome_child!content::CategorizedWorkerPool::RunTaskWithLockAcquired+0x39 [C:\b\c\b\win_clang\src\content\renderer\categorized_worker_pool.cc @ 340]
    24bdfdcc 56ae5d06 0311111c 030a8ab0 24bdfe30 chrome_child!content::CategorizedWorkerPool::Run+0x2b [C:\b\c\b\win_clang\src\content\renderer\categorized_worker_pool.cc @ 232]
    24bdfddc 54add371 031110c8 0000001a 00000000 chrome_child!content::`anonymous namespace'::CategorizedWorkerPoolThread::Run+0x14 [C:\b\c\b\win_clang\src\content\renderer\categorized_worker_pool.cc @ 35]
    24bdfe30 55af9679 031110c8 000002b8 000002b8 chrome_child!base::SimpleThread::ThreadMain+0x1c1 [C:\b\c\b\win_clang\src\base\threading\simple_thread.cc @ 68]
    24bdfe54 774aef8c 03133dc0 24bdfea0 7735367a chrome_child!base::`anonymous namespace'::ThreadFunc+0xb9 [C:\b\c\b\win_clang\src\base\threading\platform_thread_win.cc @ 92]
    24bdfe60 7735367a 03133dc0 405b4b08 00000000 kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0xe
    24bdfea0 7735364d 55af95c0 03133dc0 ffffffff ntdll!__RtlUserThreadStart+0x70
    24bdfeb8 00000000 55af95c0 03133dc0 00000000 ntdll!_RtlUserThreadStart+0x1b
```

Any reason, why this error occurs?

Comment: Are you using your own Chromium fork? Looks like you do have access to source code so you should debug it

Comment: No, I am using general chrome @Asesh